# Profile Reuse on Automapper

Tags: c#, oop, automapper

i have a base mapping profile class BaseMapping : MappingProfile, which containts this method

```
protected void Map_TAB1_to_Ent()
{
  CreateMap<TAB1, Ent>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(r => Guid.NewGuid()));
}
```

And the derived class

```
  protected class EntMapping : BaseMapping
  {
    public EntMapping()
    {
      Map_TAB1_to_Ent();
      Map_DataRow_to_Cambio();
    }
  }
```

When i try to use it in the controller, in this way;

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<TAB1, Ent>(variable)
```

I have an error of unresolved mapping; how is it possible? Am i wrong?

Comment: if you set breakpoint in `Map_TAB1_to_Ent` does it hit? Remember that you have to AddProfile to configuration